# What is the advantage of using symbolic link?

Tags: 12.04, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is different symbolic link with hard link after unlik?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36235/what-is-different-symbolic-link-with-hard-link-after-unlik)
>   [Symbolic links vs Hard links](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43593/symbolic-links-vs-hard-links)

I'm a new user to Ubuntu. And I do install some software. I see many tutorials uses symbolic link to a directory. Like this :

```
ln -s
```

Are there any advantages of using this way? Or it is the way it should be done?

Comment: Compared to what?  Question is too short and vague to be answerable.

Comment: Indeed. You need to clarify the question.

Answer (score 2):

> A symbolic link is a special file type whose data contains a filename.
>   This filename is essentially a "soft link" to another file. Whenever
>   the kernel encounters a symbolic link file type, it reads the filename
>   in the data part of the file and goes to that filename. It's as if the
>   Kernel traverses the namespace for the user. Symbolic links are nice
>   in that they are links at the namespace level rather than at the block
>   level (like hard links)<sup>1</sup>

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Read Seas](http://www.read.seas.harvard.edu/~kohler/class/05f-osp/notes/lec15.html)</sup>

Symbolic links can do 2 things:

- Link to files across file systems (since that it's an indirect link)
- Link to directories

Symbolic links are done using the `ln` command with the `-s` option.